# Android service crashes when app killed/restarted by the system

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to make specialized virtual assistant in nativescript on android. For that I need a background service constantly listening for the wake word. Now I managed to make a service, but when it's restarted after app kill with START_STICKY it crashes with `com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'tk/ozymandias/ServiceTest/Service'`.

Here's the service:

```
@JavaProxy("tk.ozymandias.ServiceTest.Service")
class Service extends android.app.Service {
    private timerId: number;

    onBind():android.os.IBinder {
        return null;
    }

    onCreate(): void {
        super.onCreate();
        if (!this.timerId) {
            this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("PING");
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    onStartCommand(intent: android.content.Intent, flags: number, startId: number) {
        return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    onDestroy(): void {
        super.onDestroy();
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }
}
```

And here's the stack trace:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to create service tk.ozymandias.ServiceTest.Service: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'tk/ozymandias/ServiceTest/Service'

StackTrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service tk.ozymandias.ServiceTest.Service: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'tk/ozymandias/ServiceTest/Service'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:108)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to create JavaScript extend wrapper for class 'tk/ozymandias/ServiceTest/Service'
    at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.createJSInstance(Runtime.java:778)
    at com.tns.Runtime.initInstance(Runtime.java:751)
    at tk.ozymandias.ServiceTest.Service.onCreate(Service.java:29)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3339)
    ... 9 more
```

You can see minimal sample project [here](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/nativescript-servicetest).
For the error to trigger you need to actually kill the app, exiting with back button works just fine.

Edit: [here's a new repo with working code](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/Nativescript-ServiceExample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out with a little help from Nick Iliev on GitHub.

Basically, when you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand` and then kill your app,
the service is restarted with `null` intent. That's the cause of the crash.

You should probably return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` to ensure you don't get `null` intents. However then your service isn't auto-restarted.

To fix that, you need a broadcast receiver that restarts your service that you invoke from `onDestroy`. Further, to ensure `onDestroy` is always called and your service isn't killed due to low memory or battery optimization, you need to make your service a foreground service.

I wrote a short-ish article about this [here](https://dev.to/ozymandiasthegreat/android-continuous-background-services-with-nativescript-42c9).

Also [here's a working example repo](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/Nativescript-ServiceExample).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure which Android version you are using, but as @Bilal mentioned the way services are handled were completely changed in Android 8, therefore if you like to support both earlier and latest versions, you will have to run specific service based on version number.

Below is an example copied from [NativeScript Geo Location plugin for fetching location in background](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/background-service.ts#L44-L79), you will have to follow something similar, and use JobService in android 8 and later versions.

```
if (application.android) {
    if (device.sdkVersion < "26") {
        (<any>android.app.Service).extend("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService", {
            onStartCommand: function (intent, flags, startId) {
                this.super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
                return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
            },
            onCreate: function () {
                _startWatch();
            },
            onBind: function (intent) {
                console.log("on Bind Services");
            },
            onUnbind: function (intent) {
                console.log('UnBind Service');
            },
            onDestroy: function () {
                console.log('service onDestroy');
                _clearWatch();
            }
        });
    } else {
        (<any>android.app).job.JobService.extend("com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService26", {
            onStartJob() {
                console.log('service onStartJob');
                _startWatch();
                return true;
            },
            onStopJob(jobParameters: any) {
                console.log('service onStopJob');
                this.jobFinished(jobParameters, false);
                _clearWatch();
                return false;
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer provide some help.

In android version 8 and above services are changed a lot.

1. You need to start service with foreground method.
2. Battery setting also matter if you are in power saver mode they system check for your service is different than normal mode.
3. Mobile os also have impact some chinese mobile os stop service of normal apps but not stop services of apps that are popular in market like whatsapp etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see you said

```
if (device.sdkVersion < "26")
```

And in the Android Developer docs it says JobService was Added in API level 21

Why dont you have it as `if (device.sdkVersion < "21")`